# Microsoft Azure Graph Authentication - Current Windows User / Hardcoded User

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, delegates

I'm new to Azure and I'm trying to read user emails using the Microsoft Azure Graph. The email account I am trying to read never changes. So I am trying to "hardcode" it somewhere using an application client secret in Azure, but no success. I can't use user/password authentication because the account is secured with MFA.

This application will be running 24/7 and will anylizing emails that are received. So I want a way to avoid entering the user/password when the app is restarted (in case of a power outage or server maintenance) or if the token is expired. I was thinking of using a Windows service and find a way to get the "Run As" user to log in to the Azure app, but I don't know if I can do that.

So, what are my options if I don't want a user login every time the application is launched?

(I am working with C#)

Thanks a lot!
Steve

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp

Comment: Thanks jdweng. I will try the Integrated Windows provider and update this post after my experience.

Comment: It's not perfect... I can't use the IntegratedWindowsProvider because it doesn't recognize the account type "Unknown". So I managed to use an integrated browser credential and use caching to store the credential on disk. So when the application starts, I use the serialized credential instead of asking to reconnect. My concern is that the credential is valid for 24 hours, so if the application is restarted after, say, 1 week, what will happen? Do I need to manually reconnect or will the app manage to silently renew the credential? Will the serialized file be updated every 24 hours?

Comment: The token would need to be refresh if it is expired.  See Token in my link.

Comment: According to [link](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Identity/1.2.0/api/Azure.Identity/Azure.Identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential.html) : `A TokenCredential implementation which launches the system default browser to interactively authenticate a user, and obtain an access token. The browser will only be launched to authenticate the user once, then will silently acquire access tokens through the users refresh token as long as it's valid.`. So.. I'm confused.. Will the Azure login will pop to reconnect?

Comment: You are making a HTTP request and there are many libraries/classes that are capable of making an HTTP request. Your link is a CLASS and the class says authentication only once which does not perform updating the token. My link shows how to send an HTTP Request and update the token.